# Quantum groups as bialgebra cohomology classes

Tags: quantum-groups, computation, bialgebras

My question below is about how to view the quantum group $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ as a *bialgebra cohomology class*.

---

**Background:** If $A$ is a bialgebra, Gerstenhaber and Schack in [Bialgebra cohomology, deformations, and quantum groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2353715) defined a double complex
$$C_{bi}^{p,q}\ =\ \text{Hom}_k\left(A^{\otimes p}, A^{\otimes q}\right), \hspace{15mm} p,q\ge 1$$
with $d$ given by the bar complex on $(A^{\otimes p})$ and the cobar complex on $(A^{\otimes q})$. First-order deformations of $A$ are classified by the second cohomology of this complex (after shifting it one down). This is plausible: such classes have representatives
$$m\ \in\ \ \text{Hom}(A^{\otimes 2},A), \hspace{10mm} \Delta\ \in\ \text{Hom}_k(A,A^{\otimes 2}),$$
which will be first-order deformations to the product and coproduct on $A$.

---

**Question:** Where can I see a computation of $\text{H}^\bullet_{bi}(U(\mathfrak{g}))$, and what the generating class $$[U_q(\mathfrak{g})]\ \in\ \text{H}^2_{bi}(U(\mathfrak{g}))\ \simeq \ \mathbf{C}$$
is?